# Sending UDP from Arduino Uno to InfluxDB

Tags: arduino, udp, arduino-uno, influxdb

So I’ve got an Arduino Uno and the Ethernet Shield V2 and connected these to a temperature sensor. Everything is working fine, the temperature is shown as desired, the problem is that I don’t seem to be able to save the results in my influxDB database.

Here my sketch:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

const int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorVal;

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};

byte host = {192, 168, 0, 153};
unsigned int port = 8089; // local port to listen on

EthernetUDP Udp;

void setup(){
//////////////////////
// PUT YOUR SETUP CODE HERE TO RUN ONCE
//////////////////////

  Serial.begin(9600); // open serial port

  Ethernet.begin(mac, host);
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found. Sorry, can’t run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }

  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println(“Ethernet cable is not connected.”);
  }
  // start UDP
  Udp.begin(port);
}

float getTemperature() {
  sensorVal = analogRead(sensorPin);
  float voltage = (sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0;
  float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5)*100;

  return temperatureC;
}

void loop(){
//////////////////////
// PUT YOUR MAIN CODE HERE; TO RUN REPEATEDLY
//////////////////////

  String line, temperature;
  delay(1000);
  temperature = String(getTemperature(), 2);
  Serial.println(temperature);
  line = String(“temperature value=” + temperature);
  Serial.println(line);

  Serial.println(“Sending UDP packet…”);
  Udp.beginPacket(host, port);
  Udp.print(“temperature value=”);
  Udp.print(temperature);
  Udp.endPacket();
}
```

These are the setting from the config file of the influxDB:

```
[[udp]]
enabled = true
bind-address = “:8089”
database = “arduino”

retention-policy = “”
InfluxDB precision for timestamps on received points ("" or “n”, “u”, “ms”, “s”, “m”, “h”)
precision = “s”
```

I would appreciate if somebody could give me some clues about what I’m doing wrong.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPBeginPacket), you want to pass a remote IP (not local IP) when you call `Udp.beginPacket`.

Does `host` represent a remote IP address? Looks like you are using `host` as a local IP to begin Ethernet as well. It is likely that you are not sending packets to a remote host. Make sure you pass a local IP to `Ethernet.begin()` and pass a remote IP to `Udp.beginPacket()`.